# Call back event after Primefaces datagrid loading

Tags: jsf, datagrid, callback, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces 2, Datagrid component. When looking up in user guide of Primefaces, I didn't see any call back function (oncomplete, onsuccess, etc...). How can I know and process a Javascript function right after the whole data in datagrid is completely and successfully  loaded ?

Thanks all !

Answer (score 0):

I think there isn't any call back function developed for datagrid and datalist.
See this open issue http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=2119[1](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=2119)

Comment: You can call a javascript function from a backing bean by invoking this this:
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute(
     "serviceNewDialog.hide();");
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute(
     "javascript:location.reload(true);");
Maybe this can help you in some way.

Answer (score 0):

I see a alternative. Firstly, if you need a callback for datagrid loading that occurs with a entire page loading, you could use the "ready" function of Jquery.

A second situation is after applying a search filter, so, possibly you will use a button to post the filter text. In this case exists the callback "oncomplete" in button, not in datagrid .

[a4j:commandButton](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_commandButton.html)

[primefaces-p](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.4/primefaces-p/commandButton.html)

Comment: After some tests, I saw a drawback. In this approach the pagination events are not caught. So the @Gesuino 's answer will do the job.
In other situations, you can use f:ajax tag.

[link](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.4/org/primefaces/context/RequestContext.html)

[link](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/requestContext.jsf)

[link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkabr.html)